# Delete all javascript from ajax modal on close/hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a website with music and with lyrics. when a song is playing users can click on the lyrics button and a modal with live lyrics appears.

if i click the lyrics for one song it works perfect but as soon as i close the modal and click on the lyrics of another song it will overlap both lyrics.

This is because  the javascript from the previous modal is still in the code.

How can i delete all data including the javascript when the modal is hidden/closed.

```
 <div>
   <a id="lyrics" href="" data-toggle="ajaxModal"  title="Lyrics">
     <i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i>
   </a>
 </div>
```

Sorry for my bad english :$

Comment: I am sure you may be using variables to store lyrics etc. On every click on a song you would need to override the values with lyrics of the clicked song!

Answer (score 0):

Using pure JS, you can use the .**innerHTML** method to clear the contents of an object.
For example:

`<div id="scripts"><script>//Your Scripts Here</script></div>`

Then

`var oScripts = document.getElementById("scripts");
oScripts.innerHTML = "";`

But don't think this will work for scripts, because once a script is loaded it doesn't matter if you delete it from the DOM.

[Removing a script tag with a specific content using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426432/removing-a-script-tag-with-a-specific-content-using-jquery)

Hope this can help you.

Also, you can try using different Method Names or calling a method with different parameters, if you are storing the lyrics on a variable you can try to clean it.

Comment: This is not deleting the javascript

Comment: hmm weird it is deleting the javascript from the code but it still loads the javascript even if its deleted

Comment: Edited.
Even if you use pure JS the code is loaded into the client machine so it will be excecuted.
You can solve your problem by clearing the variable that is storing the last song lyrics(if you are using one.)