# removing the very last Script element in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I get a script injected into our page. When navigating away, I need to remove this script...
[image]

Attached is a picture of the dom. I need to remove the:

`<script src="https://d1xem3lp7f2hdd.cloudfront.net/assets/html5_embed-3bb40f85b8941061e0ccacdbdd7c2d94.js"></script>`

script at the very end. There is no Id and the src is dynamic. I believe it is safe to say it will always be the last element in the body. How can I remove this element?

I have tried: `document.body.lastElement.remove()` with no luck..

thanks!

Comment: I don't think this will achieve what you want.. Please see this answer for details. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12426535/902874

Comment: The problem is that for the script element to exist in the DOM it would have already have to have been executed. Once it has been executed, even if you remove the tag the script is still running. What you could do (while entirely invalid html, but will render) is put an open html comment at the end of your template, `<!--`. This will stop the script from being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery, you can remove as
    `$("script").last().remove()`

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can run the following:

```
$('body script:last-child').remove();
```

This will iterate the body and get the script that is the *last child of its parent*, and afterwards will remove it from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.removeChild(document.body.lastChild);
```

should do the trick ;)

PS If you wanna be sure it is a script:

```
var dbody = document.body;
if(dbody.lastChild.tagName == "SCRIPT")
  dbody.removeChild(dbody.lastChild);
```